# Is the following ODE solvable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I would like to find solution to following ODE:
$$\frac{1}{\sin^{n-1}(x)}\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^{n-1}(x)\frac{df}{dx})-\frac{(n-1)f}{\sin^2(x)}=0$$
where $0<x\leq1,\ n\geq 2$ and $f(0)=0$. Is there any general way to solve this kind ODE? what happens if I substitute $\sin(x)$ by general functions. Any hint and reference will be appreciated.

Remark: As many of you have realised, this ODE comes from calculating the eigenfunctions of Laplacian on sphere, but actually, I care more about the following quantity (it is Steklov eigenvalue if you have seen it):
$$\frac{f'}{f}\bigg|_{x=1}$$

Comment: Is this perchance related to the Laplacian on a sphere?

Comment: Yes, you are right. This ODE comes from solving Laplacian on the sphere.

Comment: You might find something by looking up Legendre and Geigenbauer

Comment: Wolfram Alpha's general solution is given by $f(x)=c_1\sin^{1-n}-c_2\sin(x)\cos(x)\sin^2(x)^{-n/2} ~_2F_1\left(\frac12,\frac{2-n}2;\frac32;\cos^2(x)\right)$ (http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=e602dcdecb1843943960b5197efd3f2a)